# Summing bootstrap-derived confidence intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap

I have a couple things to add together- two different pools of material, and I need to know the total material.  Because of various things related to the sampling, I would like to bootstrap the sampling data from each pool.  So I generate a list of 100 masses for one pool, and 50 masses for the second pool.  Plus, I get the confidence intervals built off the bootstrap.  I can just add the mean, to get the mean total mass, but what about the CIs?

I'm still learning bootstrapping, obviously, so sorry if it's a simple question.  At first, I figured I could combine them similar to SD's, like sqrt(x^2 + y^2), but that doesn't work.  Does simple addition work?  Or do I need to build the CI's from scratch using the standard errors from each pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if i am wrong but it sounds to me like your problem is simply to get a confidence interval for the sum of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $X$ is the total mass from the sample for the first pool and Y is the total mass for the sample from the second pool.  I think for this problem you can use either the sum or the average.  To get a confidence interval for X+Y you would need to get the sampling distribution of $Z=X+Y$.  For a normal distribution a $95\%$ confidence interval for the population mean equates to the

$$\overline{x} \pm 1.96 \cdot s$$

where $\overline{x}$ denotes the sample mean and $s$ is the standard deviation.  But this relationship between confidence level does not hold for other distributions.  If you assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent with a known parametric distribution then you can solve the problem without bootstrapping.  If you don't you can generate a bootstrap confidence interval for $Z$.  Get a bootstrap sample from the sample that generated $X$ and do the same for $Y$.  Take the bootstrap estimate for $X$ and add it to the bootstrap estimate for Y to get a bootstrap estimate for $Z$.  Repeat this say 10000 times and you will be able to construct a histogram of the $Z$s.  The percentile method bootstrap is one simple way to generate approximate confidence intervals.  Let $Z_1$ be the value at which $25$ values are at it or below and let $Z_2$ be the values at which $25$ values are at it or above. Then $[Z_1, Z_2]$ is an approximate $95\%$ bootstrap confidence interval for the mean of the distribution for $Z$.

The interval is approximate and there are other types of bootstrap confidence intervals that can be more accurate for the given sample size.

Comment: So bootstrapping the additive process, rather than bootstrap the individual pools and them add them?  That makes sense, I should have thought of that.  Lack of sleep must be getting to me...  jeez!  Thanks.  I was using the percentile method for CI's, also.

Comment: I have another question.  I built this in R, and it seems to work well.  I take a random subsample of the original data for each pool (with replacement, same number of samples as in the original data), add them, and store the result 1000x (or whatever).  I then bootstrap those values and generate the final estimate of the mean, CI's, etc.                                                                                                                           Main question- is this an example of bootstrap aggregation/bagging?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out.